# Шпиц: померанский или померанцевый?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Думаю, все знаю породу собак - карликовый шпиц. У них есть разные окрасы, в том числе и светло-рыжий. Так вот, я всегда называл их "померанцевый шпиц", соответственно, от слова "померанец" - вид цитрусовых. Окрас шпицев действительно чем-то напоминает апельсин. Но в энциклопедии эта порода почему-то зовется "померанский". Разве это правильно? Прилагательное такого рода ведь, скорее, указывает на место происхождения, а не цвет.
Кто прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в энциклопедии **померанский**, то видимо таково его правильное название. Скорее всего подобное наименование произошло от исторического названия местности на юге Балтийского моря, *Померания*.